# Alterar string Python

Tags: python, string, classificação

Estou fazendo um programa para ordenar os números inseridos (não posso simplesmente usar um algoritmo de ordenação), pesquisando vi que não é possível alterar strings no python, tem alguma forma de fazer isso? Ou talvez usar lista em vez de string?

```
entrada = "32415"

for i in range(entrada):
    if entrada[i] > entrada[i+1]:
        aux = entrada[i]
        entrada[i] = entrada[i+1]
        entrada[i+1] = aux

print(entrada)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, lembrando que o python tem algoritmos de ordenação muito mais eficientes já implementados na linguagem, bastando chamar uma função para ordenar:

```
entrada = ''.join(sorted(entrada))
```

Mas, respondendo a sua pergunta: sim, listas são mutáveis, você pode converter a sua string em lista:

```
entrada = "32415"
entrada = list(entrada)
```

O seu algoritmo de ordenação tem alguns problemas, parece que você está tentando usar o "método da bolha", porém você precisa voltar a posição sempre que houver troca, nesse caso seria melhor usar o `while` ao invés do `for`:

```
i = 1
while i < len(entrada):
    if entrada[i] < entrada[i-1]:
        entrada[i], entrada[i-1] = entrada[i-1], entrada[i]
        i = max(1, i - 1)
    else:
        i += 1
```

Depois no final pode converter o resultado de volta para string usando o `join`:

```
entrada = ''.join(entrada)
print(entrada)
```

O resultado:

```
12345
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tudo bem? :D
Não sei se você está estudando algoritmos para ordenação ou quer uma solução prática do Python, mas vou seguir a segunda opção.
Para ordenar a sua variável **entrada**, uma possibilidade poderia ser o seguinte:

```
entrada = '32415'
# Nos dois próximos comandos a string vai virar uma lista.
# Em ordem crescente.
entrada = sorted(entrada)
# Ordem decrescente.
entrada = sorted(entrada, reverse=True)
# Converter de volta para string.
entrada = ''.join(str(a) for a in entrada)
```

Não sei se é isso que você quer, mas espero que sim :D

Comment: Duas dicas: 1) você não precisa converter para string o caractere no final, visto que ele já é um caractere; 2) mude o nome da variável, ter `entrada` como resultado é muito confuso, idealmente deixe a entrada imutável e defina outras para o resultado.

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado pela dica! Sou iniciante ainda e vou seguir isso sim com certeza :D